# Basic set inequality notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm viewing a basic series of youtube videos on sets. This slide has me all kinds of confused.

[Set inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPZEt.png)

His example starts with a set X. The elements of this set are denoted as $A_k \subset X$. He then takes the $\cup_i^{inf}\cap_j^{inf}A_j$. He lists k as an index in the natural numbers {1,2,3...inf}.

His demonstration shows what I believe to be an infinite series of subsets, ${A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,...}$.

His example starts with two subsets $A_{odd},A_{even}$ and proceeds do demonstrate how to take the union/intersection of the 2 different sets.

How am I supposed to derive that $A_3$ exists? Is this setup so that X is just the infinite alternating series of subsets equal to X = {$A_{odd},A_{even},A_{odd},A_{even},A_{odd},A_{even}, ... $}?

It appears to me that the set X only has two sets, {$A_{even}, A_{odd}$}, so how does it make sense to reference an $A_j$ that is equal to 3?

Comment: Seems you have several things wrong. To start, the $A_k$ are subsets, not elements of $X$. And with the notation $A_{odd}, A_{even}$, I suppose they mean $A_k=\{0,1\}$ if $k$ is odd and $A_k=\{2,3\}$ if $k$ is even (so we require at least $0,1,2,3\in X$, maybe $X=\{0,1,2,3,43\}$)

Comment: The usual notation for the set of positive integers is $\Bbb Z^+$ or $\Bbb N$ (coded here as \Bbb Z^+ and \Bbb N) although some elementary books ( not necessarily well-written) say $\{1,2,3,...\}.$ It is not good form to write $\{1,2,3..$.inf$\}$ as this suggests there is some object "inf" in the set. And whether or not the symbol $\Bbb N$ denotes $ \Bbb Z^+$ or $\Bbb Z^+\cup \{0\}$ varies by author, country, and era. On this site most users want $\Bbb Z^+=\Bbb N,$  which I have reluctantly conformed to.